# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) during compile on Java AdoptOpenJDK 14

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, adoptopenjdk

I am using Maven 3.5.0 and IntelliJ with Maven plugin installed. When I try to do 'Run As---> Maven install', I am getting the following error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building the_script 2.8.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ the_script ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ the_script ---
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.CompilerException
    at java.base/java.lang.J9VMInternals.prepareClassImpl(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.J9VMInternals.prepare(J9VMInternals.java:349)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:857)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf(InjectionPoint.java:245)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.create(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:99)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding(InjectorImpl.java:658)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:882)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:805)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:282)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:214)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:1006)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1038)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1001)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:63)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get(Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:519)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.CompilerException
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    ... 60 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.703 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-11-24T21:51:02+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/13M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project the_script: Execution default-compile of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile: org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.CompilerException
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/3.8.1/maven-compiler-plugin-3.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Please find below my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>the_script</groupId>
    <artifactId>the_script</artifactId>
    <version>${revision}</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc10</artifactId>
            <version>19.7.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2jcc4</artifactId>
            <version>4.19.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder</groupId>
            <artifactId>http-builder</artifactId>
            <version>0.7</version>
            <exclusions><exclusion> <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId></exclusion></exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-sql</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>14.0.1</release>
                    <compilerArgs>--enable-preview</compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

mvn -version

```
Apache Maven 3.5.0 (ff8f5e7444045639af65f6095c62210b5713f426; 2017-04-03T22:39:06+03:00)
Maven home: c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin\..
Java version: 14.0.1, vendor: AdoptOpenJDK
Java home: C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-14.0.1.7-openj9
Default locale: ru_RU, platform encoding: Cp1251
OS name: "windows server 2012 r2", version: "6.3", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

**UPD:**
Change AdoptOpenJDK to Java 11

```
Apache Maven 3.5.0 (ff8f5e7444045639af65f6095c62210b5713f426; 2017-04-03T22:39:06+03:00)
Maven home: c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin\..
Java version: 11.0.9.1, vendor: ojdkbuild
Java home: C:\Program Files\ojdkbuild\java-11-openjdk-11.0.9-2
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1251
OS name: "windows server 2012 r2", version: "6.3", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building the_script 2.8.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ the_script ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ the_script ---
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/plexus/compiler/manager/NoSuchCompilerException
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3137)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2357)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf(InjectionPoint.java:245)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.create(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:99)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding(InjectorImpl.java:658)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:882)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:805)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:282)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:214)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:1006)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1038)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1001)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:63)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get(Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:519)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.manager.NoSuchCompilerException
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    ... 55 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.551 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-11-25T07:40:18+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/40M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project the_script: Execution default-compile of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile: org/codehaus/plexus/compiler/manager/NoSuchCompilerException
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/admlas4/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/3.8.1/maven-compiler-plugin-3.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/admlas4/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] : org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.manager.NoSuchCompilerException
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

Comment: Does the issue occur only in IntelliJ IDEA or in the command line as well? It looks like some `openj9` branch specific bug. Try using some different JDK as a workaround (not `openj9`).

Comment: Changed AdoptOpenJDK to Java 11 Error [WARNING] Error injecting: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/plexus/compiler/manager/NoSuchCompilerException
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3137)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2357)